# I'm doing something wrong with calculating the median in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

My Hive table currently looks like this:

```
Numbers
0
0
-0.12745098
-0.218905473
0.026011561
0.235294118
-0.028
-0.052356021
0.052753355
0.008032129
0.012768817
0.115384615
0.040816327
```

The type is DOUBLE_TYPE. I would like to calculate the median. I would expect the answer to be 0.008032129, since this is the 7th observation ordering my numbers.

When I run this code (as suggested here [How to calculate median in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863139/how-to-calculate-median-in-hive)):

```
select percentile_approx(Numbers, 0.5) AS Numbers
from tryout1
```

The answer I get is : 0.0040160642570281121. This is unexpected, and not even one of the numbers in my list! Does anyone know why Hive gives me this number, and what I should fix to make it work? If you know an entirely different way to calculate the median, I am also very interested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the function percentile_approx in hive is not performing well. 
Kudos to Liza for getting an approx answer:

FROM MY TRIALs:

```
select percentile_approx(numbers , 0.5 , 10 ) as A_mdn from tryout1 ;
-0.007249852187499999
```

FROM LIZA:

```
select (percentile(cast((numbers*1000000) as BIGINT), 0.5))/1000000 as A_mdn from tryout1;
0.008032
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) sorry for my late reply!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the percentile function to compute the median and Try to cast the complete column into int or BIGINT and see if you come close to the answer. Try this:

```
select percentile(cast(g_rek_brutowinst as BIGINT), 0.5) AS g_rek_brutowinst from tryout1
```

Comment: I don't think casting it as BIGINT will work, since that would reduce all my numbers to 0.

Comment: yes, try this. Lets see we can get proper output or not.

Comment: Yes, it gave me the answer 0. Which makes sense , since it casts to INT. But in this case, its important that I get 0.008032129 and not 0.

Comment: Yes, I tried your exact code. It gave me the answer 0. Not 0.008032129.

Comment: Like this? select percentile(g_rek_brutowinst, 0.5) AS g_rek_brutowinst from tryout1

Comment: I used this simple query SELECT percentile(Numbers, 0.5) median FROM df and got the proper result as 0.008032129.

Comment: If I may ask: what are you using? Because it gives me this error : Error while compiling statement: FAILED: NoMatchingMethodException No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDAFPercentile with (double, double). Possible choices: _FUNC_(bigint, array<double>) _FUNC_(bigint, double)

Comment: can you show me your query. there is might be some mistake from your side.

Comment: SELECT percentile(g_rek_brutowinst, 0.5)median FROM tryout1 

BTW: I'm currently also trying this 

select (percentile(cast((g_rek_brutowinst*1000000) as BIGINT), 0.5))/1000000 AS g_rek_brutowinst from tryout1 , which is not very pretty but helps with keeping some digits.